# Image wont display in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am not able to display the image on my Xamarin UWP app
I have an Image in Assets folder:

```
 <Image x:Name="myBookImage1" Source="/Assets/Agile Coaching.jpeg"></Image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any specific reason you want the image in the Assets folder?

To use then 'normally' you should put them in the root and set the build action to Content. You are then able to simply do this: `<Image x:Name="myBookImage1" Source="Agile Coaching.jpeg"></Image>`

Although I would try to prevent spaces in your filenames.

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images

Comment: Where should all the images be stored in Xamarin app?
Is there a way to load images from a remote location?

Comment: Sure, from a remote location just fill in the URL

Comment: Lets say I have a web api. How to fetch the images from there